Specific array filtering - code optimization
I have a nested list where all sublists have a length 2, eg:
{{1,2}, {1,1}, {3,4}, {3,5}, ...}  

I need to filter it for two requirements:

Delete all sub-lists with the same First (except the first such sub-list)
Delete all sub-lists with First equal to Last

I get a huge construction:
DeleteDuplicates[
            DeleteCases[list, e_ /; First@e == Last@e],
        First@#1 == First@#2 &
        ]

Could it be golfed, for example, including union of duplicates in DeleteCases?

You put code optimization in your title – What does this mean? What is wrong with your current code? It's really not a huge construction. What you can do is to use DeleteDuplicatesBy[..., First] instead of DeleteDuplicates[..., First@#1 == First@#2 &].

@Domen, yes, it's much better with DeleteDuplicatesBy!  But may be is it possible to do all filtering with one function?

DeleteDuplicatesBy[DeleteCases[{a_, a_}]@list, First]

You mean like DeleteDuplicates[list, First@#1 == First@#2 || First@#1 == Last@#1 || First@#2 == Last@#2 &]?

Does it absolutely have to be one function? If not I feel like something like:
$$ $$
del = DeleteDuplicatesBy[list, First];
$$ $$
Select[del, ! Equal @@ # &]
$$ $$
is short and readable, and also gives good performance for large lists.

Not sure what you consider optimal, but in response to your comment

is it possible to do all filtering with one function?

you can certainly compose the two operations into one function and even use a point-free style:
DeleteDuplicatesBy[First]@*Select[Apply[Unequal]]@list

